# Finding the height of the B-Tree of a table in SQL-Developer

Tags: height, oracle-sqldeveloper, b-tree

Let's suppose I need to estimate te costs of the entire explain plan of an sql query, the one SQL-Developer shows. Is there somewhere this information, the height I mean, of the b-trees builted on indexes of a table? Or how can I estimate it?

Answer (score 1):

In ALL_INDEXES view I found what I was looking for. [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1069.htm#i1578369) the Oracle Documentation with all attributes you can select for an index. In my case:

```
SELECT INDEX_NAME, BLEVEL FROM ALL_INDEXES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table_name';
```

From Oracle doc on `blevel` attribute:

> B*-Tree level:
>   depth of the index from its root block to its leaf blocks. A depth of
>   0 indicates that the root block and leaf block are the same.

Comment: that is not height though. +1 blevel should be the height

Answer (score 0):

Might be wee late to the party but here goes.

```
ANALYZE INDEX INDEX_NAME VALIDATE STRUCTURE;

SELECT name, height,lf_rows,lf_blks,del_lf_rows FROM INDEX_STATS;
```

this will yield a table with a column "height".